# Can you cast an object to a class dynamically?

Tags: android, kotlin, reflection, casting

I would like to cast an object based on one of it's fields, the field would have the right value for the object.

for example

```
object as object.class
```

object.class would be equivalent to a class, like Int or any other kotlin class.

is it possible?

Comment: Please provide detail information your question is not clear ???

Comment: I have a List of base class e.g List<BaseClass> , I would like to take each item and cast it to it's actual type. the actual type will be a property inside the object , for example item as items.type

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do this if your Required class extend the base class

```
(list.get(pos) as Class).requeiedfunction
```

Comment: I am not sure you understood what I want to accomplish, I would like to do as follow

data.value?.get(0) as data.value?.get(0).subClass
of curse the subClass property is a property in the baseClass which is being initialized by the subClass type

Comment: if you data.value?.get(0) and  data.value?.get(0).subClass has same patient class you can do this For example data.value?.get(0) has  patient  as view and data.value?.get(0).subClass has also had patient  as view then you can do this but if these patient  class are not same then you cannot do this

Answer (score 0):

With an expected interface and a BaseClass you an accomplish this with type safety as needed. This is using objects as input, but following this pattern any type instance will work.

The interface forces the type to be assigned, and can allow you to maintain Type at scoping without any magic. It allows you to handle all expected cases easily.

```
interface ClassCast<out T> {
    val type: T
}

open class MyClassBase
class MyClassOne : MyClassBase()
class MyClassTwo : MyClassBase()
class LonerClass

val myObjOne = object : ClassCast<MyClassBase> {
    override val type = MyClassOne()
}

val myObjTwo = object : ClassCast<MyClassBase> {
    override val type = MyClassTwo()
}

val nonRelatedObj = object : ClassCast<LonerClass> {
    override val type = LonerClass()
}

fun castToClass(item: ClassCast<Any>): Any {
    return when (item.type) {
        is MyClassOne -> {
            println("We have an Instance of class one")
            MyClassOne()
        }
        is MyClassTwo -> {
            println("We have an Instance of class two")
            MyClassTwo()
        }
        is LonerClass -> {
            println("Class that doesnt inherit from base type")
            LonerClass()
        }
        else -> {
            println("Unexpected type: $item")
            throw Exception("Unexpected type cant be cast")
        }
    }
}

castToClass(myObjOne) // Prints: "We have an Instance of class one"
castToClass(myObjTwo)) // Prints: "We have an Instance of class two"
castToClass(nonRelatedObj) // Prints: "Class that doesnt inherit from base type"
```